# How to restore a model in tensorflow without making the tensorboard messy?

Tags: tensorflow

When I restore my model via `tf.train.Saver`, the loss in my tensorboard becomes very messy,

[image]

it seems that it starts over from the `0` iteration when it gets restored, is there a way to make it look nicer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variable (with trainable=False) to indicate the iteration, and increase the variable as the training proceeds. Whenever we want to add the summary to the tensorboard, we run that variable and pass the result to `add_summary` as `global_step`.

For example

```py
# the variable mentioned before, counting training steps
train_steps = tf.get_variable('train_steps', shape=[], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(), trainable=False)

step_op = tf.assign(train_steps, train_steps + 1)

# update learn_step whenever optimization is performed
with tf.control_dependencies([step_op]):
    opt_op = optimize(loss)

...
train_steps, _, summary = sess.run([train_steps, opt_op, merged_op], feed_dict=feed_dict)
# write summary to tensorboard
writer.add_summary(summary, train_steps)
# save model
saver.save(sess, filename)
```

Comment: Instead of using the `step_op` if you pass your `train_steps` to the optimizer when calling the `minimize` function like this:
`optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer. minimize(cost, global_step=train_step)` it will be updated automatically. More precisely, every time the optimizer updates the trainable variables, it will increase it's `global_step` parameter too.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, you're definitely right. But the above implementation will come in handy when we do not relate logging operations to optimizing operations. For example, when we do reinforcement learning, we may want to log the score only when an episode is done.